# Plotting dataset using griddata without cancelling outliers

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have an x, y, z dataset which contains a rather large number of points.
x and y are the positions while z is the actual observable at those coordinates.

Most coordinates have a zero value for z, while only a few of them define lines (with smoothly changing z) in the 2D map.

If I plot it with

```
scatter(x,y,c=z))
```

I get only very faint lines as the scatterpoints with color defined by `z=0` are overlapping with the nonzero values of z. If I decrease the size of the points to reduce overlap, I can't see them anymore.

Here an example of the best I could get using scatter (blue is zero `z`, other colors are non-zero `z`).

[image]

So, I thought of instead using

```
data = np.genfromtxt('data')

x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]*3.0
z=data[:,2]

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100, min(y):max(y):1000]

from scipy.interpolate import griddata
grid_z0 = griddata((x, y),z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

im = imshow(grid_z0,origin="lower",extent=[0,0.175,-0.15,0.15]) # zoom in on specific part of data
```

to get a denser grid of points and possibly get wider lines due to the cubic interpolation of points around them.

However, then it seems like `griddata` is removing the non-zero z, considering them as outliners, thus hiding any possible features and the whole grid plots a zero `z`.

Is there any python/matplotlib/... feature or trick I am missing to plot this in a nice way?

I am trying to make plots that would look something like the ones you can see in Fig. 2 (2) of [https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.085409[2](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.085409) (you can see the figure without downloading the paper) with possibly some kind of glow around the lines.

The data I used is in this [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5qp6vk90w7t1cb/data?dl=0).

Comment: I thought I wouldn't copy the 279000 lines of data into here, hence the link. I understand your suspicion due to the rather generic name. I cannot really reduce it in a meaningful way as the whole point of my problem is related to the denseness of the data. I'll try to see if I can strip a small part that contains just a small part of the line. If you look at my code, you'll see exactly how to open and read it, using numpy.genfromtxt. As for the minimal verifiable example, I imagined that's exactly what I provided. I stripped away all the parts of my code that are not necessary.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're getting at. If using outside data is against the guidelines of the minimal examples, I'll try to see if I can find a function that generates data giving the same problem I have. My data is the output of some heavy calculations so can't use the same procedure for this. If I had a fitting function in the first place, all would be much easier and I wouldn't have to ask this question.

Comment: As for my first comment, it was an answer to a comment that has been deleted in the meanwhile. I presume it's because the commenter verified my data is just numerical data and not a virus or anything. But again, I understand the suspicion downloading random data from a random guy on the internet.

Comment: Ok I see the problem. Let's suppose we break the rules for a moment. Still, it would be necessary that you describe the data. Are those completely random positions? Is it already gridded data? And much more importantly, it seems you are doing quantitative science here, e.g. physics, so what is the meaning of the data? What scale should the resulting plot have? Or is this just about getting some yellow line where larger data values are? (The latter might be easier, but useless for physics.)

Comment: Ok for supposing this for a while. I'll be happy to oblige if no other way. The positions are not random. They are evenly spaced points in x and y direction. The x are k-points in reciprocal space and E are energies. The z data describes the strength of k-point contributions at certain energies. The larger the value, the greater the strength. So, yes, ideally, it should be plotted in a quantitative way. In the screenshot, you see it is not "yellow only", so scatter is not too bad, but I'm trying to make it better.

Comment: And other comment, if you use `norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()` in the `scatter`-plot, you'll actually see that there are several other lines that are not seen in the linear scaling plot. That's how it supposed to be. Only the ones that are strong enough with a linear plot should be seen.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarifications. If you want I can delete the question and try to incorporate the comments directly into a new question. I have to catch a flight soon, so I'll check up on your advice tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you may change the scatter, e.g. to set the size of the points without energy to 0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data/some_solidstate_physics_data.txt')

x=data[:,0]; y=data[:,1]*3.0; z=data[:,2]

plt.scatter(x,y,c=z, s=np.log10(z+1), cmap="PuRd", vmin=-500)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since the data is already gridded, there is for sure no need to use griddata, this will only smooth out the data. Instead just reshaping the data into a grid is enough.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data/some_solidstate_physics_data.txt')

x=data[:,0]; y=data[:,1]*3.0; z=data[:,2]

ux = np.unique(x); uy = np.unique(y)
Z = z.reshape(len(ux),len(uy)).T

dx = np.diff(ux[:2])[0]; dy = np.diff(uy[:2])[0]
ext = [ux.min()-dx/2.,ux.max()+dx/2.,uy.min()-dy/2., uy.max()+dy/2.]

plt.imshow(Z, extent=ext, aspect="auto", cmap="magma")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since the grid is very dense, it looks somehow pixelated.

You may of course also bin your data into larger chunks. For example joining the data of 3x3 pixels into one and taking the maximum value, using [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from  scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d
data = np.genfromtxt('data/some_solidstate_physics_data.txt')

x=data[:,0]; y=data[:,1]*3.0; z=data[:,2]

ux = np.unique(x); uy = np.unique(y)
h, ex, ey,_ = binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z, bins=[ux[::3],uy[::3]], statistic='max')

dx = np.diff(ex[:2])[0]; dy = np.diff(ey[:2])[0]
ext = [ux.min()-dx/2.,ux.max()+dx/2.,uy.min()-dy/2., uy.max()+dy/2.]

plt.imshow(h.T, extent=ext, aspect="auto", cmap="magma")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Having those techniques at your disposal you may then decide to beautify your result at the expense of quantitative accuracy.
E.g. applying a gaussian filter, [`scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html) as well as `interpolation="gaussian"` in the plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters
data = np.genfromtxt('data/some_solidstate_physics_data.txt')

x=data[:,0]; y=data[:,1]*3.0; z=data[:,2]

ux = np.unique(x); uy = np.unique(y)
Z = z.reshape(len(ux),len(uy)).T
Z = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(Z, 3)

dx = np.diff(ux[:2])[0]; dy = np.diff(uy[:2])[0]
ext = [ux.min()-dx/2.,ux.max()+dx/2.,uy.min()-dy/2., uy.max()+dy/2.]

plt.imshow(Z, extent=ext, aspect="auto", cmap="magma", interpolation="gaussian")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is pretty amazing. I'll take some time to get the best result and post my solution as a comment. Thanks a lot, this is all the inspiration I needed.

Comment: I think I forgot to use `origin="lower"` in several places in this answer. So some of the images seem flipped upside down.